# Flutter toggle a number by tapping on it

Tags: flutter, dart, numbers, toggle

Imagine a stock portfolio app with a large headline number at the top.

How can I code a toggle command in such that the number, by tapping on it, would result in a switch between 2 numbers? (it is basically just another number that is of different computation)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you include your current snippet that you;ve tried so far?

Comment: Have not tried much. Currently it's just a dummy number on the app. Just wondering how does one code out a toggle command to switch that particular number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using int here, you can use `bool` to switch between true and false

```dart
class TeNA extends StatefulWidget {
  const TeNA({super.key});

  @override
  State<TeNA> createState() => _TeNAState();
}

class _TeNAState extends State<TeNA> {
  int number = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (number == 0) {
              number = 1;
            } else {
              number = 0;
            }
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: Text("number $number"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [dart](https://dart.dev/)